# web2py - deleting admin application removes ability to get to myapp/appadmin

Tags: admin, web2py

I have a single web2py app which I have set up to be the default by using

```
routers = dict(
           BASE=dict(
                     default_application='myapp',
                     ),
           )
```

As recommended in the docs. I want to remove the admin app, but retain the ability to administer by app using my app/appadmin. Is this possible? I tried simply removing the app, but now when I go to https://example.com/appadmin, I get redirected to https://example.com/admin?send=%2Fappadmin and this replies (quite reasonably) with "invalid controller (default/index)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appadmin.py controller delegates authentication to the admin app, so you cannot access appadmin without the admin app. The only exception is that you can access the /appadmin/manage functionality described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Application-Management-via-privileged-users--Experimental-), as that is authenticated via the application itself.

Alternatively, you can hack your application's appadmin.py controller to change how authentication is managed -- see [here](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/applications/welcome/controllers/appadmin.py#L41).